# How to change input text color if it is blank submit by help of php and javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, css

In index.php I have input area for emailId, php code to show error by user and my in login page I have php code to store user email id in database(mysql). And I don't want user submit blank email id to handle this problem I wrote "if (empty($uemail)){" but I want to show user input area is empty by changing changing border color of input text area into red.

**index.php**

```
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">

<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['error'])){
echo '<script type="text/javascript">   
function downIt() {
document.getElementById("input").style.cssBorder = "color: red";
}
</script>';
}
unset ($_SESSION['error']); 
session_destroy ();
?>
```

**login.php**

```
$uemail = $_POST['email'];
if (empty($uemail)){
$_SESSION['error'];
Header( 'Location: index.php');
exit;
}
else{
query code....here....
}
```

Comment: `session_start();` has to be called before any output so possibly sessions do not work as you may think (or do work because of output buffering but still you should fix that), also the `$_SESSION['error'];` should cause `Undefined index` notice and do not actually set up the session, correct is: `$_SESSION['error'] = true;`. idk why you separate the handler of form submit to another file but common way is that you handle form submit right before the form html output and in case of error just do something like: `<input ... <?= ($error?' class="error"':'') ?>>` and you dont need sessions at all.

Comment: if i understood your question, you can use attribute required in html tag and. I agree with @Kazz put session_start() as first line code... example required tag <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>

Comment: Thank you everyone for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you do not try just HTML5 instead?
For example:

```
<style>
    .was-validated input:invalid {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
</style>

<script>
    // Bootstrap code
    // Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
    (function () {
        'use strict';
        window.addEventListener( 'load', function () {
            // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
            var forms = document.getElementsByClassName( 'needs-validation' );
            // Loop over them and prevent submission
            var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call( forms, function ( form ) {
                form.addEventListener( 'submit', function ( event ) {
                    if ( form.checkValidity() === false ) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    }

                    form.classList.add( 'was-validated' );
                }, false );
            } );
        }, false );
    })();
</script>

<form method="post" action="login.php" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

But if you want to use PHP anyway, I do not see reason to use Javascript.

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

$error_border = '';
if ( isset( $_SESSION[ 'error' ] ) ) {
    $error_border = ' style="border: 1px solid red;"';
}

unset ( $_SESSION[ 'error' ] );
?>

    <form method="post" action="login.php">
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"<?php echo $error_border; ?> />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>

<?php session_destroy(); ?>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start(); // resume existing session

$uemail = $_POST[ 'email' ];
if ( empty( $uemail ) ) {
    $_SESSION[ 'error' ] = 1;
    Header( 'Location: index.php' );
    exit;
} else {
    query code....here....
}
```